# Extend object using underscorejs

Tags: underscore.js

I have an array of objects. The `weightedAverage` property needs to be updated. Initially `weightedAverage` set to 0. Please refer my script below for more details.

Expected Ouput is:

```
[
      {
        area:"Digital",
        category:"Medical",
        qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ32",
        qqId:"step1",
        type:"Reduce",
        val:1,
        **weightedAverage:80**
      }
];
```

**Script**

```
var arrayFlatten = [
      {
        area:"Digital",
        category:"Medical",
        qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ32",
        qqId:"step1",
        type:"Reduce",
        val:1,
        weightedAverage:0
      },
      {
        area:"Digital",
        category:"Analytics",
        qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ32",
        qqId:"step1",
        type:"Reduce",
        val:1,
        weightedAverage:0
      },
      {
        area:"Digtal",
        category:"Medical",
        qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ32",
        qqId:"step1",
        type:"Reduce",
        val:10,
        weightedAverage:0
      }
    ];


    //groupBy qid
    var groupqId = _.groupBy(arrayFlatten,'qId');
    console.log(groupqId);
    //value dividedby total value
    var result = {};
    _.each(groupqId, function(val, key) {
      console.log(val);
        result.qId=key;
        result.weightedAverage = _.reduce(val, function(memo, v) {
          console.log(v);
          return memo + v.val;
        }, 0) / 15 * 100;
    });
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: With the above . My final output is : {qId: "wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ321", weightedAverage: 80}.

But I am looking for the below
[
      {
        area:"Digital",
        category:"Medical",
        qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ32",
        qqId:"step1",
        type:"Reduce",
        val:1,
        **weightedAverage:80**
      }
];

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by simple for loop

```
var final=[];
for(var i = 0 ; i < arrayFlatten.length ; i++){
  arrayFlatten[i].weightedAverage = 80;
    final.push(arrayFlatten[i]);
}
console.log("FINAL",final);
```